# Run java executable from a groovy script on linux

Tags: java, linux, groovy

I know it's a bit strange but i'm trying to run the java executable from a groovy script:

```
def mycommand = "java -version"
def env = System.getenv().collect { k, v -> "$k=$v" }
def mycommandOut = mycommand.execute(env,null).text
println mycommandOut
```

this work well on windows but when I run it on Linux it seems to does nothing.

If i set `mycommand = "ls -la"` it works like a charm.

If i set `mycommand = "foobar"` i get: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "foobar": error=2

Any hints?

Comment: Does it seem to do nothing or there's an error? What happens on the target Linux box when you execute that command in a shell? Is the java executable found?

Comment: It does nothing. I think java is found because if i set mycommand="foobar" i've go a java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "foobar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `java -version` prints the info to STDERR on Linux.  But you are capturing the STDOUT.

```
def proc = "java -version".execute()
proc.waitFor()
def version = proc.err.text
```